# Remote viewing software

Tags: cross-platform, remote-access, remote-desktop

I am building a series of scientific instruments that run computers with Windows 7 Embedded Standard inside, right now to connect to that computer we either connect a VGA cable to a monitor or connect RDP/Wifi from a router in the instrument. But I would like to find some software that I can connect to the computer from a laptop easily. I am thinking the closest thing to doing this would be LogMeIn or TeamViewer, but if I'm not mistaken both of these need a person on the other end to authorise this connection. Any ideas? I prefer cross-platform if I have a choice. Open to anything here.

Comment: TeamViewer does not need a person on the other end to authorise this connection.

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be installing a VNC server. Once installed and activated you can login from remote clients as if you'd be on the physical console.

Advantages:

- cross-platform support, any mix of Linux, Windows, OSX clients/servers can be achieved with a relatively consistent access method
- the same desktop session can be shared with full keyboad&mouse control or in view-only mode by one or more clients simultaneously, password-protected
- SSH-friendly for encrypted access, can be tunnelled
- several free VNC packages available

Disadvantages:

- can't share server's sound or USB devices with remote clients

Comment: That seems to be what we are doing now  we have a WINDOWS 7 Embedded Standard computer connected to a router and we RDP to the computer when we connect to the WiFi. My though is though that it could be easier.  Like we could use something that is literally as simple as tapping or clicking the name of the device and connecting.

Comment: At least on Linux it is possible, with the proper setup, to start a client and connect to a server just by clicking on a desktop icon.

Comment: Ok I'll look into this

Comment: I agree with Dan, use VNC. I tried a few, way back, and for years have been doing just what you want to with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TightVNC

Answer (score 0):

LogMeIn would work for you. You do need to install the software, of course, and for that you obviously need someone present at the client. Once it is installed, however, you can initiate a connection with no one present. I use it to work on my own machines when I am working remotely. I have had no problems using it on Windows and Mac OS X (including using an OS X client to connect to a Windows machine).